# shell loop did not finish after exec a docker cmd?

Tags: docker, shell

I had met a problem while running the code below:
I want to have a loop under a dir and loop in the sub dir.

```
cd /mysql_back
ls   | while read line
do
    echo $line
    if [[  -d "$line" ]];then
        echo $line 
        cd $line
        ls *.txt | while read datafile
        do 
            echo "start load data:" $datafile
            echo "copy ${datafile%.txt} from '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql_back/${line}/${datafile}' delimiter ',' csv;" >> add_data.sql
        done 
        docker exec -i $pg_continer psql -U postgres -d $line  -f "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql_back/${line}/add_data.sql" 2>/dev/null
        echo "start next dir"
        cd ../
    fi    
done
cd ${RootPath}
```

the outputs:

```
dstore_notification
dstore_notification
start load data: global.txt
start load data: message.txt
start load data: templet_info.txt
start load data: templet.txt
start next dir
```

the loop ended after finish docker cmd in the first sub dir,

after removing the docker cmd code `docker exec -i $pg_continer psql -U postgres -d $line  -f "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql_back/${line}/add_data.sql" 2>/dev/null`

the outputs:

```
dstore_notification
dstore_notification
start load data: global.txt
start load data: message.txt
start load data: templet_info.txt
start load data: templet.txt
start next dir
dstore_rbac
dstore_rbac
start load data: rbac_admin.txt
start load data: rbac_app_admin_role.txt
start load data: rbac_app_admin.txt
start load data: rbac_app_role.txt
start load data: rbac_service_app.txt
start next dir
```

I can't figure out why
anybody can tell me why this happens?
and how should I do the docker cmd in every sub dir?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are running the docker exec command with -i. This means that you are running the exec command in interactive mode with the terminal and docker container waiting for input from yourself and providing output from the container.

To run the container to the background, you need to use -d as opposed to -i. This will then also allow the script to continue as expected.

As a side note. Don't parse the output of ls. Instead use "for datafile in *"

Comment: That's great. If you could like and accept the answer, that would be appreciated.